# maximum number of points in convex position on a grid

Tags: geometry

Guys please help me with this simple question:

What is the maximum number of points in convex position in a $n\times m$ grid ( say grid is made by intersection of two sets of parallel lines   , one with $n$ lines and the other $m$ lines )? ( here i guess the maximum be $2(m+n)-4$ .

remark: what would be the answer if the grid is made of two sets of concentric circles ( instead of lines) ( i mean if the grid is made of intersections of a set of n concentric circle and another set of m concentric circles)..
any suggestion will be very much appreciated.....

Comment: What exactly do you mean by convex position? For instance, why won't picking all the points work?

Comment: it is quite clear what i mean( in all textbooks) : a set of points are in convex position if and only if they form vertices of a convex polygon.

Comment: Is there any harm in mentioning that? I was only trying to help fwiw, but whatever.

Comment: From your formula (using $n=2$, $m=3$), it seems that you are allowing points to be on the edges of the convex polygon, i.e. points that are 180 degree vertices. Is that right? Because if so, then just choose all the points on the perimeter of the grid.